# Migrate from Magento 2.3 to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, migration

I have a **brand new Magento instance** (2.4) and an old instance (2.3) with product/order/cms/theme data.

I would like to **migrate the data from Magento 2.3 to 2.4**, is there any way to do this?

**I have tried upgrading** the existing 2.3 (cli) site but running into a lot of errors - and to move to a new set up, where I know 2.4 is working, seems to be a sensible option, but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Initially update the magento using these commands

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
composer update

Moreover Enable the developer Mode and run deployment
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean